# How i can put radio button on image?

Tags: css, html

I want to code something like this:

[image]

I used CSS on my radio buttons but they are not positioning with my image as I want. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: Yes, post your code, and please explain what you want in more detail.  What does "not positioning through my selected image" mean?  I suspect a language barrier issue here, so please be as detailed as possible so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you want.  If not, please post some code to help us help you...

This may be what you are looking for though:

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://www.25score.com/attachments/article/691/small/Taco%20Bell%20200x200%20(small).jpg")
}

input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <input type="radio">
</div>
```